# Bash wait until finishing the job and execute the next command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem with my bash script:

```
cmd1='/usr/bin/wget http://mysite/folder/'
$cmd1 > "/var/www/html/log/data.log" 2>&1 & 

cmd2='/usr/bin/indexer --rotate --all' 
$cmd2 > "/var/www/html/log/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" 2>&1 &
```

Getting the data by wget takes much time, but next command executes before wget finishes the job.

How can I check if wget has been finished and execute the next command.
Thanks!

P.S: I have tried to use sleep between these commands and the second command executes multiple times. I need just once.

Comment: BTW, storing commands in string-type variables gets you the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the trailing `&`s. `&` causes commands to run in the background. The default behavior where they run in the foreground is what you want.

```
cmd1='/usr/bin/wget http://mysite/folder/'
$cmd1 > "/var/www/html/log/data.log" 2>&1

cmd2='/usr/bin/indexer --rotate --all' 
$cmd2 > "/var/www/html/log/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" 2>&1
```

Side note, you really shouldn't store commands in variables. Use functions. There's also no reason to write out `/usr/bin`.

```
cmd1() { wget http://mysite/folder/; }
cmd1 > /var/www/html/log/data.log 2>&1

cmd2() { indexer --rotate --all; }
cmd2 > /var/www/html/log/"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" 2>&1
```

You could now store the entire command, redirections and all, in the functions; you may have noticed you couldn't do that when using variables.

```
cmd1() { wget http://mysite/folder/ > /var/www/html/log/data.log 2>&1; }
cmd2() { indexer --rotate --all > /var/www/html/log/"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" 2>&1; }

cmd1
cmd2
```